# Delphi unit for msctf.h header file (from Platform SDK)?

Tags: delphi, header-files, platform-sdk

Is there any Delphi unit available corresponding **msctf.h** header file from Platform SDK?

I have checked Delphi 2010 source folder, but it seems Delphi doesn't come with that.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: I can't find anything useful. Looks like you may need to translate the interfaces that you need.

Comment: Just a wild guess: might the JEDI project have the translations? http://www.delphi-jedi.org/

Comment: @JanDoggen, checked that. JEDI doesn't have it.

Comment: It's a big library, but how much of it do you need. Just translate the parts you do need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio's [MIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367300%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to generate a type library (.tlb) from the .idl file and then use Delphi's tlibimp.exe to generate the Delphi interface unit.

The problem with the original .idl is that it doesn't contain a [library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) statement so I added it manually (otherwise MIDL wouldn't generate the .tlb).

See if [the result](http://pastebin.com/PBcJeuKV) helps you (you may still need to fix some parts by hand).

Comment: Thank you! That'll help a lot :)